# Speed Test Changes for Wireless, but not for Wired

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

This problem is challenging my view of the universe.

Let me describe what's going on. I have two computers -- my desktop machine is hardwired (Ethernet) to my router and my laptop is using wireless to the router.

As you may know, Comcast has a "Test Your Speed" page. The page allows you to select the geographic location of the server that you will communicate with during the test.

Now here's where it get's interesting. I live near Chicago. If I test my speed against the Comcast's Chicago server, my desktop (wired) and laptop (wireless) speed scores are about the same (~29 Mbps download). If I test against a Boston server, which is about 1,000 miles from Chicago, the wired connection stays at about 29 Mbps whereas the wireless drops down to about 26 Mbps. If I test against a Seattle server, which is about 2,000 miles from Chicago, the wired speed goes down to 22 Mbps while the wireless speed drops to 13.5 Mbps!

As the server moves farther from Chicago, the laptop's wireless connection becomes slower than the wired connection. I've tested with other geographic locations and this pattern is consistent. I would expect both the wired and wireless connections would become slower equally.

Can anyone explain why I am seeing this behavior.

Btw, the laptop is a Lenovo W500 with an Intel 5300 AGN wireless device.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Speedtest's to servers further and further away are not testing your connection, they are testing internet conditions.  While interesting, they prove nothing. A wireless slowdown could be caused by a neighbor on the same channel deciding to click a link that causes a few hi-res pics to be loaded etc. In short, to test speed use the WIRED connection and the close server, and do it more than once and take the average.  Other speed tests (via wireless, further servers etc) will only show you inefficiency as compared to the baseline you establish with the wired connection to the close server.

Comment: The wireless slowdown was not caused my neighbor downloading a video file. I performed the test repeatedly and continuously saw the same result. The wireless performance became worse as the serer moved farther away. I didn't just test it once or twice -- It was closer to 12-15 times and the results were the same the entire time. Close to Chicago was good and the farther from Chicago the worse it became.

Comment: I get it, and I also didn't disagree.  You're seeing unexplainable differences. I only told you what a "speedtest" can prove under sane conditions.  Add other variables and it becomes impossible to filter the inefficiencies.  How do you know what the neighbor sharing a wireless channel did, where you watching at that second?  Also don't use comcast's own speedtest, they play routing games to keep you from wanting to call them =]